# C#: String divided into substrings, excluding tabs

Tags: c#, arrays, string, substring

I have a file that looks something like this:

```html
0   4   5
6   9   9
```

etc, with three numbers in each row, separated by tabs. I have an array of the lines from the file:

```html
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(theFile);
```

For each line, I am calling a function whose intended result is to return an array of integers. Here's what my code looks like as of now:

```html
 public int[] getPoint(string line)
    {
        int xlength= line.IndexOf(" "); //find location of first white space
        int x= Int32.Parse(line.Substring(0, xlength)); //find x-coordinate and turn it from a string to an int

        int ylength = line.IndexOf(" ", xlength); //find next white space
        int y = Int32.Parse(line.Substring(xlength + 1, ylength)); //y-coordinate starts after first white space and ends before next

        int z = Int32.Parse(line.Substring(ylength + 1, line.Length)); //z starts after 2nd white space and goes through end of line
        
        return new int[] { x, y, z }; //return a new point!
    }
```

My problem is with the IndexOf(string) function. It does not recognize tabs. How could I write this so that each my getPoint function achieves its purpose? Thank you.

Comment: A tab is signified by "\t". I suggest using the Split() method.

Comment: Consider to not re-invent the String.Split() method or the .NET TextFieldParser class.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about reading CSV files. Please clarify why existing answers did not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `IndexOf()` with tabs, not with spaces:

```
int xlength= line.IndexOf("\t"); //"\t" - to find tabs
```

Also, use `"\t"` in every `IndexOf()` call.

Answer (score 0):

How about this using Split and Linq and LinqPad

```
void Main()
{
    var lines = new List<string> { "0\t4   5", "6\t9\t9" };

    lines.Select(l => GetPoint(l)).Dump();
}

static int[] GetPoint(string s)
{
    var values = s.Split(new[] {' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return values.Select(v => int.Parse(v)).ToArray();
}
```

Of course you would use

```
File.ReadLines("path").Select(l => GetPoint(l)).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `ReadLines` method instead. `RealLines` will read the file line by line into memory as requested. Also, try using the `Split` method. I would also add error handling in case the found string is not parseable to an `int`. Here is some code to guide you but you may need to adjust it to fit your needs:

```
foreach (var thisLine in File.ReadLines(theFile))
{
    int[] point = getPoint(thisLine);
}

public int[] getPoint(string line)
{
    // Split by tab or space
    string[] portions = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' });

    int x = Int32.Parse(portions[0]); //find x-coordinate and turn it from a string to an int

    int y = Int32.Parse(portions[1]); //y-coordinate starts after first white space and ends before next

    int z = Int32.Parse(portions[2]); //z starts after 2nd white space and goes through end of line

    return new int[] { x, y, z }; //return a new point!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit of additional capacity to the suggestions above, you could use Regex.Matches() as follows:

```
        string line = "1\t-25\t5";

        var numbers = Regex.Matches(line, @"-?\d+");
        foreach (var number in numbers)
            Console.WriteLine(number);
```

And then parse those numbers as integers.

This has two benefits.

1. It can handle negative numbers, and
2. It will pull out the numbers successfully, even if tabs weren't used or are not reliable.